# JSPdf with VueJS MultPage error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, jspdf

I'm having a problem trying to use JSPdf with Vuejs. I've got a tutorial on the internet ([this one](http://www.techumber.com/how-to-convert-html-to-pdf-using-javascript-multipage/)) that shows how to print all the contents of a div (because it was not possible.) But the test works perfectly, in mine, even if I can adapt, the PDF comes in blank, can anyone help?

My code adapted with VueJS:

```
methods: {
   GerarPdf(){
        let source      = $('#div')
        let cache_width = source.width()
        let a4          = [595.28, 990.89]

        let canvasImage = ''
        let winHeight   = a4[1]
        let formHeight  = source.height()
        let formWidth   = source.width()

        let imagePieces = []

        imagePieces = [];
        imagePieces.length = 0;

        source.width((a4[0] * 1.33333) - 80).css('max-width', 'none');

        return html2canvas(source, {
            imageTimeout: 2000,
            removeContainer: true
        })
        .then(canvas => {
          console.log(canvas)
          canvasImage = new Image();
          canvasImage.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
          let totalImgs = Math.round(formHeight/winHeight);

          for(let i = 0; i < totalImgs; i++) {
              let canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
                  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
              canvas.width = formWidth;
              canvas.height = winHeight;
              ctx.drawImage(canvasImage, 0, i * winHeight, formWidth, winHeight, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
              imagePieces.push(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
          }
          console.log(imagePieces.length);
          let totalPieces = imagePieces.length - 1;
          let doc = new jsPDF({
              unit: 'px',
              format: 'a4'
          });
          imagePieces.forEach(function(img){
              doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 20, 40);
              if(totalPieces)
                  doc.addPage();
              totalPieces--;
          });
          doc.save('techumber-html-to-pdf.pdf');
          //source.width(cache_width);
        })
      }
}
```

Comment: Is `#div` an element with height and width in the document when this runs?

Comment: @RoyJ Yes, The div has height and width, but still...